# Calculating the total time for running a scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Hi i am using scrapy to scrape the sites

I had written spider,fetched all the information and saved in to csv files through pipeline.py

**pipeline.py code**

```
class Examplepipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        log.msg("opened spider  %s at time %s" % (spider.name,datetime.now().strftime('%H-%M-%S')))
        self.exampledotcomCsv = csv.writer(open("csv's/%s(%s).csv"% (spider.name,datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y,%H-%M-%S")), "wb"),
                   delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        self.exampledotcomCsv.writerow(['field1', 'field2','field3','field4'])           

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
            log.msg("Processsing item " + item['title'], level=log.DEBUG)
            self.brandCategoryCsv.writerow([item['field1'].encode('utf-8'),
                                    [i.encode('utf-8') for i in item['field2']],
                                    item['field3'].encode('utf-8'),
                                    [i.encode('utf-8') for i in item['field4']]
                                    ])
            return item 


    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        log.msg("closed spider %s at %s" % (spider.name,datetime.now().strftime('%H-%M-%S')))
```

In the above code i can able to get `start time and end time of spider`, but after closing the spider i want to calculate and display the `total time` taken by spider that is `difference between start time and end time` 
So how can i do that, we can write this functionality in spider_closed method?

Please let me know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not:

```
def spider_opened(self, spider):
    spider.started_on = datetime.now()
    ...

def spider_closed(self, spider):
    work_time = datetime.now() - spider.started_on
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how can spider_closed method access value from spider_opened ,method......

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, in my answer i showed that: `spider.started_on = datetime.now()` - we are keeping a value inside the spider object, and in `spider_closed` we retrieve that value from the spider.

Comment: Hi warwaruk i know this is a new question but i can expect this question related to this too, actually we can display total time in spider_closed method as u said above, but is there any way to send a mail like "Scraping has been completed" to our mail.If possible please provide me an example(dont mind) code of sending a mail after scrapy running.

Comment: @Kouripm I don't have an example for you, but there is some docs: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/email.html